# Spring Boot: Why do i get Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported , when i'm sending multipart/form-data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

*) I'm newbie to spring boot.Currently was creating a Post service which would accept text , image & userId & store them in h2 DB.
*) When i try to test my service with Postman i'm getting 415 Error code which says "error": "Unsupported Media Type".
*) This is my controller file code for post call

```
@PostMapping("/posts")
    public ResponseEntity<Post> createPost(
            @RequestPart(value = "text") String text,
            @RequestPart(value = "image", required = false) MultipartFile image,
            @RequestPart(value ="userId") Long userId
    ) {
        System.out.println("text is : " + text);
        if(image != null) System.out.println("image is : " + image);
        System.out.println("userId is : " + userId);

        PostDTO postDTO = new PostDTO();
        postDTO.setText(text);
        postDTO.setImage(image);
        postDTO.setUserId(userId);

        Post createdPost = postService.createPost(postDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(createdPost, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

*) This is my entity modal file

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String text;

    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition = "mediumblob")
    private byte[] image;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    // Default constructor
    public Post() {
    }

    // Constructor with text and userId parameters
    public Post(String text, Long userId) {
        this.text = text;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    // Constructor with text, image, and userId parameters
    public Post(String text, byte[] image, Long userId) {
        this.text = text;
        this.image = image;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

Below is my postman response

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zxXh.jpg)

You can see here i'm providing request with Content-Type: multipart/form-data.

I don't even see getting console logs inside my controller .

I tried providing image as an optional form-data thinking might be issue with image type . but still facing the same issue. Had went through different questions on Stackoverflow but didn't found any solution.
Expecting someone to help rectifying the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @RequestParam annotation can also be used to associate the part of a "multipart/form-data" request with a method argument supporting the same method argument types. The main difference is that when the method argument is not a String, @RequestParam relies on type conversion via a registered Converter or PropertyEditor while @RequestPart relies on HttpMessageConverters taking into consideration the 'Content-Type' header of the request part. @RequestParam is likely to be used with name-value form fields while @RequestPart is likely to be used with parts containing more complex content (e.g. JSON, XML)

In simple terms, if you're dealing with basic data like names and numbers from forms, use @RequestParam. If you're dealing with more complex data like JSON or XML from a file upload or a more intricate form, use @RequestPart.

Eg.

```html
@PostMapping("/posts")
    public ResponseEntity<Post> createPost(
            @RequestParam(value = "text") String text,
            @RequestPart(value = "image", required = false) MultipartFile image,
            @RequestParam(value = "userId") Long userId) {
        System.out.println("text is : " + text);
        if (image != null) System.out.println("image is : " + image);
        System.out.println("userId is : " + userId);

        PostDTO postDTO = new PostDTO();
        postDTO.setText(text);
        postDTO.setImage(image);
        postDTO.setUserId(userId);

        Post createdPost = postService.createPost(postDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(createdPost, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Akshay for the detailed explanation . Appreciate it :)